# A stored proc to copy table data including any default value or binding data via a SQL script running within SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to be able to copy a table and it's data and also still have any *default value* or *binding* (as it is labelled within SQL Server Management console) constraints copied over.

The script below is a testing script to demonstrate the idea. The last line I assume needs to be replaced with a call to a custom stored proc?

Note: The source table (`aSourceTbl`) schema varies and can change over time.

```
--TEST SETUP 
--Delete the prev tables so test script can be replayed
IF OBJECT_ID('aSourceTbl', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE aSourceTbl;

IF OBJECT_ID('aSourceCopyTbl', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE aSourceCopyTbl;

--Simple table to demonstrate table copying does not carry over the table constraits
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[aSourceTbl](
    [aValue] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DELETED] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

--Add some dummy data
INSERT INTO aSourceTbl (aValue, DELETED) VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO aSourceTbl (aValue, DELETED) VALUES (3,4);

--Add constraints of default values of 0 in this case 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[aSourceTbl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_aSourceTbl_aValue]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [aValue]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[aSourceTbl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_aSourceTbl_DELETED]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DELETED]

--Actual Required SQL script from here down 
--The line below works nicely but does not copy the 2 constraints from the lines above into the new table. 
--TODO QUESTION: Replace line below with the same functionaility + the constraints are also copied into new table
Select * INTO aSourceCopyTbl FROM aSourceTbl
```

Could you please help me by suggesting a suitable stored proc that can replace the last line in above SQL snippet? Any help greatly appreciated :)

References:

- [Similar SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600172/how-to-copy-a-table-schema-and-constraints-to-a-table-of-different-database/) however focuses on PK constraints. I am only interested in default value constraints in this case.

Comment: Is this a one-time script, or is it something you plan to incorporate within the application?

Comment: An ad-hoc script. Used to (i) take copies of tables, (ii) then trial update/algos on the copied table data, (iii) then depending on results possibly swap the copied table back in to replace the original table. Hence maintaining constraints is required. Please note: most of the script above is just test related. The last line just needs to be enhanced so as to also copy table constraints (+data etc).

Comment: Is this a script that you'll be using in an application, or is it just for maintenance purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute this code after the last row which will replicate the defauld constraints to the new table (replace the variables with your table names).

```
declare @table_name sysname, @new_table sysname, @cmd varchar(max)
select @table_name = 'SOURCE_TABLE', @cmd = '', @new_table = 'TEST_TABLE'


select @cmd = @cmd+'ALTER TABLE '+@new_table+' ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_' +@new_table+'_'+a.name+'] DEFAULT '+b.definition+' FOR['+a.name+']; 
' 
from sys.columns a 
join sys.default_constraints b on a.object_id = b.parent_object_id and a.column_id = b.parent_column_id
where a.object_id = object_id(@table_name)  

print @cmd
exec (@cmd)
```

Comment: Nice answer. I added a cursor to loop through all of the constraints and added them to my new table. Thanks!